# optimised comparison algorithm

Tags: algorithm, comparison

I'd like to create an algorithm to be used in a spreadsheet as follows:

If you have a number of cells with different values:
    A= 3
    B= -2
    C= 10
    D= -8 etc
And you want to balance all the negative values back to zero with the fewest changes to the positive values (ie 'A' can balance 'B' and 'C' can balance 'D' with 2 changes, BUT, 'C' can balance both 'B' and 'D' with only 1 change to a positive value)

That in a nutshell is what I would like an algorithm/formula to achieve. The first layer of additional complexity would then be to only consider positive values above a certain threshold (eg >5).

If that's possible, or any ideas of how to compare the values, identify one and balance the negatives to zero in the fewest number of moves and identify the positive would be appreciated!

Thanks

[This is the closest approach I've found to date but doesn't identify](http://www.mathmeth.com/tom/files/settling-debts.pdf)

Comment: Why can't you implement the algorithms that are in the paper you linked to?

Comment: If a move is the use of a positive number, and you want to use the fewest moves, wouldn't sorting your cells and taking the largest magnitude positives off in descending order, and reducing the 'balance' of each positive by taking off negatives (smallest (i.e. most negative) first), ascending (skipping where the magnitude of the negative is too much) until you have no 'balance' to the chosen positive left, or until there is no negative with a small enough magnitude you can deduct?

Comment: This appears to be a variation of the 1 dimensional [Bin Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) with variable size bins. The positive values are the bins, the negatives are the items.

Comment: I think you're right, specifically the VM packing variant of the Bin Packing Problem, with variable size bins. It sounds enormously more complicated and difficult to solve on the Wikipedia page than when Rajomelly describes it I must say.

Comment: Thanks! That gives me a direction to start in. To put it into context, I would apply it to equity within a number of properties and evaluate if it were worth refinancing one property to release equity that can be distributed amongst other properties to increase their % equity, and therefore lower mortgage costs.